# How to change citation style for specific sentence?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, natbib

When I make a reference at the beginning of a sentence I have one citation style, but when I make a reference at the end I have another.

The class I'm using has the `\cite{}` command containing only the latter style.

How can I change the citation style for some specific citation?

Example:

The citation style for `\cite{kahneman1979prospect}` is:

> [Kahneman and Tversky 1979]

But I can only use this style at the end of a sentence.

If I start the sentence citing something such as:

"According to..."

My citation style should be:

> Kahneman and Tversky (1979)

Is it possible to create this new style (preferably a new command in the preamble)?

I've looked some other classes and they have it implemented in a new command such as`\citeN{}`:

```
\def\citeN{\def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
    \def\@cite##1##2{##1\if@tempswa , ##2]\else{]}\fi}%
    \def\citeauthoryear##1##2##3{##2 [##3}\@citedata}
```

I used the above code in my current class and preamble. Unfortunately it is still not working, but hopefully gives a starting point.

**EDIT:**

This is a minimal example with correct and incorrect style for each case.

> main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\begin{document}

\section{Citation Style I}

\begin{itemize}
\item According to \cite{kahneman1979prospect} \dots is incorrect.
\item According to \citet{kahneman1979prospect} \dots is incorrect.
\item According to Kahneman and Tversky (1979) \dots is correct.
\end{itemize}

\section{Citation Style II}

\begin{itemize}
\item This is correct \dots \citep{kahneman1979prospect}.
\item This is incorrect \dots (Kahneman and Tversky, 1979).
\end{itemize}

\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

> references.bib

```
@article{kahneman1979prospect,
  title={Prospect theory: An analysis of decision under risk},
  author={Kahneman, Daniel and Tversky, Amos},
  journal={Econometrica: Journal of the econometric society},
  pages={263--291},
  year={1979},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}
```

> Output file

[image]

Comment: With classic BibTeX you can set the style globally. Local changes are not possible. Nice question tho! ;) Maybe it is possible with `biblatex`

Comment: You could have a look at the `usebib` package by Enrico Gregorio.

Comment: @Ruben I looked up Natbib reference sheet and could get very close to what I need using `\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{a}{}{;}`. This makes `\citep{}` style correct: [Kahneman and Tversky 1979], but makes  `\cite{}` output Kahneman and Tversky [1979]. I just need the year inside parentheses. Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `\citet{}`? Worked fine for me until I switched to Biber/Biblatex. If not, please provide a minimal working example which we can compile to reproduce the problem. That is, code for a small document and one or two bib entries, obviously, since you'll need to cite something.

Comment: @cfr Included minimal working example, as requested. Thanks!

Comment: Are you up for using `biblatex` as tagged? Since your MWE does not use `biblatex` I'm not sure if you really want that. With `biblatex` you'd probably use `\parencite` and `\textcite`, but you would have to change the bracketing.

Comment: @moewe Yes! I'm up for it. I included `biblatex` because the previous comments mentioned it. How do I change the bracketing for `\parencite`? I tried it and it seems promising, but it messed a little my References section because I have to use a certain bibliography style. Is it possible to use my own bibliography style (`.bst` file) along with `biblatex`? Thanks!

Comment: A quick and dirty `natbib` solution would be to use `\bibpunct{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{;}` and then make your own version of `\citet` defined as `[\citealt{...}]`.

Comment: You can't use a `.bst` with Biblatex, but it is generally easier to customise than BibTeX as you use regular LaTeX to style things.

Comment: @AlanMunn Shouldn't the brackets be reversed? That is, `[`, `]` in `\bibpunct` and `(`, `)` for `\citet`?

Comment: As cfr mentions it is definitely not possible to use your exsiting `.bst` styles together with `biblatex`. Maybe there is a `biblatex` style that comes close to the `.bst` you use, but if you need to stick to the `.bst` you can't use `biblatex`.

Comment: @AlanMunn This quick and dirty `natbib` solution is perfect! In fact, it worked exactly as I was expecting, since I could keep the `.bst` I'm using. The solution to my problem was as simple as `\citealt{kahneman1979prospect}]` along with `\bibpunct{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{;}`. Thanks!

Comment: Ok I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty solution using `natbib` which won't require you to change any of your existing code.  The idea is to set `natbib` to use round parentheses for regular `\citet` citations and redefine `\citep` to use the unbracketed `\citealp` with your own square brackets added.

We redefine `\citep` rather than `\citet` since the latter is much more likely to be used with its optional argument for pages etc., whereas `\citep` is typically used with a simple list of citations.

Here's a full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{kahneman1979prospect,
  title={Prospect theory: An analysis of decision under risk},
  author={Kahneman, Daniel and Tversky, Amos},
  journal={Econometrica: Journal of the econometric society},
  pages={263--291},
  year={1979},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{;}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\renewcommand{\citep}[1]{[\citealp{#1}]}

\begin{document}

\section{Citation Style I}

\begin{itemize}
\item According to \cite{kahneman1979prospect} \dots is now correct.
\item According to \citet{kahneman1979prospect} \dots is now correct.
\item According to Kahneman and Tversky (1979) \dots is correct.
\end{itemize}

\section{Citation Style II}

\begin{itemize}
\item This is now correct \dots \citep{kahneman1979prospect}.
\item This is incorrect \dots (Kahneman and Tversky, 1979).
\end{itemize}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]