# Change the format from [author, year] to (author year) at the end of the citation

Tags: citing, natbib

Now my format is [Bauer et al., 2007], by using the **\citep**. But I want use the (Bauer et al., 2007). And I tried the method provided by the thread [How to change citation style for specific sentence?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391099/how-to-change-citation-style-for-specific-sentence). It did not work. Could any one help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! As usual here can you please show us a short tex code and the relevant bib entry resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) you have  examples of using `\citep` that produce the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for quick help! I would take examples next time. And the it seems that I did not include \bibliographystyle{natbib}. After adjustment, it works.

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem, would you be so kind as to "answer" your own question? That way, others can see more easily that your problem has been solved and may also learn something from it.

Comment: Running `\bibliographystyle{natbib}` is not a general solution. Instead, execute either `\setcitestyle{round}` *after* loading `natbib` or change the loading command to provide the `round` option, i.e., `\usepackage[round,<other options.]{natbib}`.